# Kubernetes MLflow Service Pod Connection

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, mlflow

I have deployed a build of mlflow to a pod in my kubernetes cluster. I'm able to port forward to the mlflow ui, and now I'm attempting to test it. To do this, I am running the following test on a jupyter notebook that is running on another pod in the same cluster.

```
import mlflow

print("Setting Tracking Server")
tracking_uri = "http://mlflow-tracking-server.default.svc.cluster.local:5000"

mlflow.set_tracking_uri(tracking_uri)

print("Logging Artifact")
mlflow.log_artifact('/home/test/mlflow-example-artifact.png')

print("DONE")
```

When I run this though, I get

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='mlflow-tracking-server.default.svc.cluster.local', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/mlflow/runs/get? (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

The way I have deployed the mlflow pod is shown below in the yaml and docker:

Yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mlflow-tracking-server
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mlflow-tracking-server
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mlflow-tracking-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mlflow-tracking-server
        image: <ECR_IMAGE>
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
        env:
        - name: AWS_MLFLOW_BUCKET
          value: <S3_BUCKET>
        - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: aws-secret
              key: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
        - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: aws-secret
              key: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mlflow-tracking-server
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: mlflow-tracking-server
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: mlflow-tracking-server
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 5000
      targetPort: http
```

While the dockerfile calls a script that executes the mlflow server command: `mlflow server --default-artifact-root ${AWS_MLFLOW_BUCKET} --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000`, I cannot connect to the service I have created using that mlflow pod.

I have tried using the tracking uri `http://mlflow-tracking-server.default.svc.cluster.local:5000`, I've tried using the service EXTERNAL-IP:5000, but everything I tried cannot connect and log using the service. Is there anything that I have missed in deploying my mlflow server pod to my kubernetes cluster?

Comment: It'll be beneficial to share a kubernetes manifest for the pod running your Juniper notebook. Can you do that, please?

Comment: I don't have the current manifest for jupyter notebook. What woul be something that I need to look for in that?

Comment: How was it deployed? as a pod or as a deployment?

Comment: Providing you know the name and the namespace, `kubectl get pod %pod_name% -n %pod_namespace% -o json` should return the manifest.

Comment: Can you share the whole Dockerfile for the tracking server, please? Without it, it's very hard to reproduce the issue.

Comment: So to oversimplify this, you have no ways to access the mlflow uri from jupyterhub pod. What i would do here is check the proxies for the jupyterhub pod. If you dont have .svc in NO_PROXY you have to add it. A detailed reason is that you are accessing the Internal .svc mlflow url as if it is on open internet. But actually your mlflow uri is only accessible inside the cluster. If adding .svc doesnt work for no proxy doesnt work we can take a deeper look at that. The ways to check the proxies is by taking ‘ kubectl get po $JHPODNAME -n $ JHNamespace -o yaml’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **mlflow-tracking-server** service should have *ClusterIP* type, not *LoadBalancer*.

Both pods are inside the same Kubernetes cluster, therefore, there is no reason to use *LoadBalancer* Service type.

> For some parts of your application (for example, frontends) you may want to expose a Service onto an external IP address, that’s outside of your cluster.
>   Kubernetes ServiceTypes allow you to specify what kind of Service you want. The default is ClusterIP.
>
> Type values and their behaviors are:
>
> - **ClusterIP**: Exposes the Service on a cluster-internal IP. Choosing this
>     value makes the Service only reachable from within the cluster. This
>     is the default ServiceType.
> - **NodePort**: Exposes the Service on each Node’s IP at a static port (the NodePort). A > ClusterIP Service, to which the NodePort Service routes, is automatically created. You’ll > be able to contact the NodePort Service, from outside the cluster, by
>     requesting :.
> - **LoadBalancer**: Exposes the Service
>     externally using a cloud provider’s load balancer. NodePort and
>     ClusterIP Services, to which the external load balancer routes, are
>     automatically created.
> - **ExternalName**: Maps the Service to the contents
>     of the externalName field (e.g. foo.bar.example.com), by returning a
>     CNAME record with its value. No proxying of any kind is set up.
>
> [kubernetes.io](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types)

Comment: I thought so too so I recreated the service with ClusterIP type, but I still get the same error when trying to test it from jupyter notebook on a pod in the cluster.

Comment: OK. Possible, there is an issue with the port(5000) not being listened. `targetPort: http` is also suspicious.

Comment: @JMV12, Can you check your `targetPort` as suggested by Paul and change it to the the port that container listen to?

Comment: @JMV12 Have you managed to fix the issue? What was the root cause?

Comment: Honestly I'm unsure. I tore down the pod containing mlflow and my jupyternotebook and spun each up again and they now work.

Comment: OK. I'm glad it works now. I'm pretty sure ClusterIP was a root cause.

Answer (score 0):

So to oversimplify this, you have no ways to access the mlflow uri from jupyterhub pod. What I would do here is check the proxies for the jupyterhub pod. If you dont have .svc in NO_PROXY you have to add it. A detailed reason is that you are accessing the Internal .svc mlflow url as if it is on open internet. But actually your mlflow uri is only accessible inside the cluster. If adding .svc doesnt work for no proxy doesnt work we can take a deeper look at that. The ways to check the proxies is by taking ‘ kubectl get po $JHPODNAME -n $ JHNamespace -o yaml’